# OnCheckChanged triggered multiple times for CheckBox in repeater in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, repeater

I've got a repeater in an update panel. the contents of the repeater is refreshed every 5 secs.
(AsyncPostBackTrigger bound to  the tick event of a timer)

In every item of the repeater there's a checkbox with autopostback set to true.
I want the state of each checkbox to be preserved after each refresh of the repeater, that's why I save it's state in Page.Session. And then in the tick event handler I set the Checked value of the Checkbox to the value from the session. Unfortunately, this seems to trigger the OnCheckedChanged event and thus I do not know anymore which event handler invocation comes from user interaction and which from code.

Anybody knows why the OnCheckChanged is triggered more than once and how can I
prevent the extra occurencies? Is there a way to prevent the AsyncPostBackTrigger from triggering the OnCheckedChanged event of the Checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out which control caused the post back by checking `Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")`, which returns the ID of the control.  However...

I won't know for sure without reading your code, but you shouldn't need to worry about tracking which checkboxes are checked, the checked state should be saved in viewstate (unless you have it turned off...)  So if this isn't the case there is probably something else wrong with your page.

Comment: I guess I should read a bit about viewstate, I haven't turned it off on purpose but not sure whether it's turned on or off... still really a greenhorn in asp.net.

Comment: I guess the viewstate wouldn't be preserved as with each refresh of the repeater, databinding happens again, thus the repeater items and their controls are created over and over again...

Comment: Why re-databind each time?  Try only databinding on the initial page load and not on each async post back.

Comment: because the number of elements can change over time, it depends on some objects that can be CRUDed somewhere else.

Comment: Try using the code I mentioned in my post in an If block such that if any control besides the checkbox list caused the post back go ahead and re-databind, but if it was the checkbox list then don't.  maybe that will work?